# A connection along a curve is $C^{\infty}(I)$-linear.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $c:I \to M$ smooth. We define

$$\mathfrak{X}(M)_c := \Big\{X \in C^{\infty}(I,TM): X(t) \in T_{c(t)}M, \quad \forall t \in I\Big\}.$$ Then $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)_c$ is called a **vector field along the curve $c$**.

Now, we get a unique map $$\frac{\nabla}{dt}: \mathfrak{X}(M)_c \to \mathfrak{X}(M)_c$$ defined by  $$X \mapsto \frac{\nabla}{dt}X.$$

Now, one of the rules for this map that we have is that for $Z \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, we get $$\frac{\nabla}{dt}(Z \circ c) = \nabla_{c'}Z$$ where $\nabla$ is the levi-civita connection (metric and torsion free connection). Now, in my notes, it says that $\nabla_{c'}Z$ is $C^{\infty}(I)$-linear,and I presume they mean with respect to the first argument, but I am unsure exactly what they mean. Since the connection is with respect to an underlying smooth manifold $M$ with metric $g$, i.e. SR-manifold $(M,g)$, we usually think of a connection (regardless of whether metric/torsion-free) as being $C^{\infty}(M)$-linear in the first argument. Can someone explain how to view this as a $C^{\infty}(I)$-linear map as opposed to $C^{\infty}(M)$-linear map? I did not understand the explanation in the notes.

Clarification: $C^{\infty}(M) := C^{\infty}(M,\mathbb{R})$ and $C^{\infty}(I) := C^{\infty}(I,\mathbb{R}).$

Edit: Here is the explanation given (somewhat paraphrased): The expression $\nabla_{c'}Z$ can be interpreted as an element in $\mathfrak{X}(M)_c$ in the following way. The map $$\mathfrak{X}(M) \times \mathfrak{X}(M) \to \mathfrak{X}(M)$$ given by $$(W,Z) \mapsto \nabla_{W}Z$$
is $C^{\infty}(M)$-linear in the first slot. Thus for fixed $Z \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ the vector $\nabla_{W}Z(p) \in T_pM$ depends only on $W(p)$. Therefore, it makes sense to define $\nabla_{\nu}Z := \nabla_{W}Z$ where $W$ is any vector-field such that $W(p) = \nu$. As a consequence we  obtain a well-defined linear map $$T_pM \to T_pM$$ $$\nu \mapsto \nabla_{\nu}Z$$ We may extend this to a $C^{\infty}(I)$-linear map
$$\mathfrak{X}(M)_c \to \mathfrak{X}(M)_c$$ $$X \mapsto \nabla_{X}Z$$ by setting $\nabla_{X}Z(t) = \nabla_{X(t)}Z \in T_{c(t)}M$. Setting $X = c'$ in the above, we see that $\nabla_{c'}Z$ is a $C^{\infty}(I)$-linear map.

Comment: this is indeed weird. The only reason for $C^{\infty}(I)$ to come up is to talk about the product rule verified in the $X$ slot.

Comment: @peak-a-boo I have added an explanation. I can´t quite parse it though.

Comment: I am for example not sure what he means by "for fixed Z, the map depends only on $W(p)$". Surely the map will depend on which values $Z$ takes in $TM$, although, I suppose he must mean something along the lines of fixing $Z$, evaluating at $p$, and *then* choosing a vector field $W$ that we send to $\nabla_{W}Z(p)$?

Comment: Or actually, fixing $Z$, evaluating $Z$ at $p$, and then looking at the map $W \mapsto \nabla_{W}Z(p)$. Well, it is one sense the same as I said above, maybe reformulated.

Comment: Ok, so what they’re saying is that for any smooth curve $c:I\to M$, any $f\in C^{\infty}(I)$ any $Z\in\mathfrak{X}(M)$ and any $X\in\mathfrak{X}(M)_c$, we have $\nabla_{fX}Z=f\nabla_XZ$. This of course only makes sense because of the lemma about $(\nabla_WZ)(p)$ depending only on $W(p)$. But ok… this is kind of a trivial statement, which is why I was confused initially (keep in mind that $\frac{\nabla}{dt}$ is not $C^{\infty}(I)$ linear).

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I am still not quite sure why it becomes $C^{\infty}(I)$. But he seems to use this in one step of the proof of the uniqueness of $$\frac{\nabla}{dt}$$ as well as in the proof of $$\frac{\overline{\nabla}}{dt}X = \frac{\nabla}{dt}X +\Pi(X,c’)$$ for $x \in \mathfrak{X}(M)_c$, where he treats the second fundamental form $\Pi$ as $C^{\infty}(I)$-bilinear.

Comment: Should be $X \in \mathfrak{X}(M)_c \subset \mathfrak{X}(\overline{M})$ above. And the curve $c:I \to M \subset \overline{M}$.